# Scrape image using CURL?

Tags: linux, image, shell, curl, web-scraping

I inspected this [Manga Page](https://w10.mangafreak.net/Read1_Hajimete_No_Gal_45) and got this [image link](https://images.mangafreak.net/mangas/hajimete_no_gal/hajimete_no_gal_45/hajimete_no_gal_45_18.jpg).

I tried using `curl` command to download the image but it returned `html` data instead.

Command i used : `curl https://images.mangafreak.net/mangas/hajimete_no_gal/hajimete_no_gal_45/hajimete_no_gal_45_18.jpg`

Returned data :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<title>Entering Mangafreak...</title>
<style type="text/css" >h1,p{color:#404040;text-align:center}#myDiv,#myDiv1,h1,p{text-align:center}body,html{width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0}body{background-color:#fff;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:100%}h1{font-size:1.5em}p{font-size:1em;margin:10px 0 0}#myDiv1{display:none}img{max-width:100%;height:auto;width:auto}</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  (function(){
    var a = function() {try{return !!window.addEventListener} catch(e) {return !1} },
    b = function(b, c) {a() ? document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", b, c) : document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", b)};
    b(function(){
      var a = document.getElementById('cf-content');a.style.display = 'block';
      setTimeout(function(){
        var s,t,o,p,b,r,e,a,k,i,n,g,f, xDznyGO={"wN":+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]))/+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]))};
        g = String.fromCharCode;
        o = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
        e = function(s) {
          s += "==".slice(2 - (s.length & 3));
          var bm, r = "", r1, r2, i = 0;
          for (; i < s.length;) {
              bm = o.indexOf(s.charAt(i++)) << 18 | o.indexOf(s.charAt(i++)) << 12
                      | (r1 = o.indexOf(s.charAt(i++))) << 6 | (r2 = o.indexOf(s.charAt(i++)));
              r += r1 === 64 ? g(bm >> 16 & 255)
                      : r2 === 64 ? g(bm >> 16 & 255, bm >> 8 & 255)
                      : g(bm >> 16 & 255, bm >> 8 & 255, bm & 255);
          }
          return r;
        };
        t = document.createElement('div');
        t.innerHTML="<a href='/'>x</a>";
        t = t.firstChild.href;r = t.match(/https?:\/\//)[0];
        t = t.substr(r.length); t = t.substr(0,t.length-1); 
        a = document.getElementById('jschl-answer');
        f = document.getElementById('challenge-form');
        ;xDznyGO.wN*=+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]))/+((!+[]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]));xDznyGO.w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xDznyGO.wN+=+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]))/+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]));xDznyGO.w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xDznyGO.wN-=+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))/+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]));xDznyGO.wN-=+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))/+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]));xDznyGO.wN-=+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]))/+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[]));xDznyGO.w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a.value = (+xDznyGO.wN + t.length).toFixed(10); '; 121'
        f.action += location.hash;
        f.submit();
      }, 4000);
    }, false);
  })();
  //]]>
</script>

</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="20">
<td align="center" valign="middle">
<div id="myDiv1"><div class="cf-browser-verification cf-im-under-attack">
  <noscript><h1 data-translate="turn_on_js" style="color:#bd2426;">Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.</h1></noscript>
  <div id="cf-content" style="display:none">

    <div>
      <div class="bubbles"></div>
      <div class="bubbles"></div>
      <div class="bubbles"></div>
    </div>
    <h1><span data-translate="checking_browser">Checking your browser before accessing</span> mangafreak.net.</h1>

    <p data-translate="process_is_automatic">This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.</p>
    <p data-translate="allow_5_secs">Please allow up to 5 seconds&hellip;</p>
  </div>

  <form id="challenge-form" action="/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="s" value="6977b7c5689e60d0637e781cc9d42b048667542c-1564646132-1800-AT6wnbzFcJ7/IWIZ7MeJA7CHxZgNogpaJiSlrZjpDR9uZt3xLsJEs3LJzVfvvdfvNDetfDL70qQB0SvIwtGURGtXqF8VwI7PTpj2eeDBPB273Ff3+X3mLUXPommEBIx+cI8i4HRVM0H2tPIdP98ZbNUmDKRFDoLsSU5rDYt9r1+fN7YY9OwXDQN8wgsNBR/lNbwn3Ugr2nFTQzNNBtCSIjU="></input>
    <input type="hidden" name="jschl_vc" value="38d158d1174811116b7423d15274558d"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="1564646136.76-AFFAHwDTSK"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="jschl-answer" name="jschl_answer"/>
  </form>

</div>
</div>
<div id="myDiv">
<h1>Entering Mangafreak...</h1>
<img src="data:image/gif;charset=binary;base64,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">
<p>Please wait while we make things better for you.</p>
</div>
</td></table></body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why is this happening. Am i missing something? or does the `https` protocol has anything to do with it?

Please, any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Looks like that server is set up to first serve up a HTML page with javascript that redirects to the real content. Probably to prevent scraping images.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to comment your post so I'm writing the reply. I wanted to do the same thing with PHP and curl. Seeing your post I decided to dig deeper.

I've just checked the HTML code and I think that it isn't the page's code that redirects you but rather it's the server. JS creates a timeout function that submits a form which contains hidden fields with encrypted data, I presume it's used on the server-side to determine where you should be redirected.

Comment: yeah that kinda makes sense. then  can i download the redirected image using [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) or something cause my browser always loads the image somehow when i go to the image URL

Comment: I haven't done it ever so can't help. But I need to add one thing because of your comment. When you open any page, the server checks if you have a valid cookie or session created. If not, the "waiting website" is loaded instead which forces you to wait a few seconds, makes the call to the server (by submitting the form), the latter creates the cookie/session and finally redirects you to the proper page by changing HTML headers of the call. After that you'd be ready to do anything. The key is to create a proper cookie or session so the server thinks that you're a legit user and not a bot.